# disabling scroll on textarea

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a textarea with some content and links.

When i use this

```
textarea.mx_internal::getTextField().mouseEnabled = false;
textarea.mx_internal::getTextField().mouseWheelEnabled = false;
```

the scroll is disabled, that is what i want to achieve.

But the texarea also has some html links, they also become not clickable.

How can I achieve a situation where the textarea has active links working properly on mouseclick, but the textarea should not be scrollable by the mouse wheel.

The issue shows up in mac only, not in windows. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried simply setting `mouseWheelEnabled` to false and `mouseEnabled` to true?

Comment: @puggsoy yes. the scroll issue is still there in the case.

Comment: Well all I can think of other than that is setting the `TextArea`'s `verticalScrollPolicy` value to `ScrollPolicy.OFF`. It might not stop the mousewheel though.

Comment: @puggsoy thanks i have a solution. I have posted the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for my case. Here it is.

```
  textarea.mx_internal::getTextField().enabled=true;
    textarea.mx_internal::getTextField().mouseWheelEnabled = false;  

    textarea.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL,
    function(event:MouseEvent):void{callLater(setScroll,new Array(textarea));});

    function setScroll(field:TextArea):void{
        field.verticalScrollPosition = 0;
    }
```